# Sharepoint REST API: get items from a list. If they do not exist, then retrieve ListItemEntityTypeFullName value of the List. All with a single call

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-list

I have a small application that when initialized gets some information from a Sharepoint List via REST call.

Those information eventually needs to be modified from inside the application, again via REST API, and saved in the same List. 
That is why, when I originally get those information, I also store the ListItemEntityTypeFullName value of the List in a global scope variable, that will be later passed in the POST function.

My code to get the list items is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        listType = data.d.results[0].__metadata.type
    });
```

If no element is found, the only way I know to store the ListItemEntityTypeFullName value would be to make a second ajax call as it follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        listType = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
    });
```

Now, my question is: is there any way to make both requests in a single call, so that if no elements have been found in the List, I can still get somewhere the ListItemEntityTypeFullName value? I am trying to optimize the number of calls I have to make to keep the application fast and smooth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Still need to create another request if there is no items in list.
As when list have no items, data.d.results array will be empty.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var listType;
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.d.results.length > 0)
        {
          listType = data.d.results[0].__metadata.type;
          console.log(listType);
        }
        else
        {
          GetListItemEntityTypeFullName();
        }
    });
});

function GetListItemEntityTypeFullName()
{
   $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks11')/?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    }).done(function(data) {
        listType = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
        console.log(listType);
    });
}
</script>
```

Another option to get ListItemEntityTypeFullName is to generate directly with this format:

SP.Data.ListNameListItem

Comment: Yes, this was my approach so far, I guess there is no way to merge the two calls together. Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes. Or you could directly use SP.Data.ListNameListItem directly without doing a request .